# iOS auto-layout constraints

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm unsure of how I should set up some constraints in my auto-layout storyboard in iOS.

I have a textbox and a button next to it, constrained to each other, and they're both constrained to the sides of their superview by 20.  It works great for iPhones/iPods.  Moving up to iPad, however, the textbox becomes too wide.  Is there some way to set a "max width" on the text box in order to allow some growth, and allow the constrains to the superview grow after that point?

It feels like I'm approaching it all wrong, do I have the wrong approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The constraint**

You can set a constraint for "width less than or equal to X" (whatever your value X is).

Then pair that with your "trailing edge space to the edge of the superview is equal 20".

**The Conflict**

This will not work as it is though as if the superview is too wide it will create a conflict.

**Priorities**

What you can do though is give the "edge space" constraint a priority of 1 less than the priority of the width constraint.

So if the width constraint has a priority of 750 (which is default) then give then space constraint a priority of 749.

This has the effect of telling AutoLayout. "If there is a conflict, then break gracefully by 'removing' the space constraint and keeping the width constraint".

Answer (score 1):

You can set a width constraint and in the right side of the screen, instead of equal, select less than or equal (or something like this). This will add a maximum width to your UI element.

Answer (score 1):

You can add width constraint which can be set the constant with the equal value, for example 100 or you can add equal greater than 100 or less equal...

Answer (score 1):

you can use Ctrl+Drag with in a text field to set fix width.